# Focus button from javascript withour clicking it

Tags: javascript, button, focus

I call

```
element.focus();
```

Where element is HTMLInputElement of type=button.
But then the browser clicks the button! That's in mozilla and chrome.

How do i highlight the button with selection, but not initiate the click event?

Comment: Please show additional relevant code... focus will not execute the click event. Something else must be involved.

Comment: Cannot assist without relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i've identified the reason.
I was handling the onkeydown event for Enter key.
The solution is to use
e.preventDefault();

```
function ConvertEnterToTab(s, e, numSkipElements) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.htmlEvent.keyCode;
            if (keyCode === 13) {
                var tabIndex = s.tabIndex || s.inputElement.tabIndex;
                if (numSkipElements == undefined) {
                    numSkipElements = 0;
                }

                var nextElement = FindNextElementByTabIndex(tabIndex + numSkipElements);
                if (nextElement != undefined) {
                    nextElement.focus();
                    return e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.htmlEvent.preventDefault(); // this is the solution
                }
            }
        }

        function FindNextElementByTabIndex(currentTabIndex, maxTabIndex) {
            if (maxTabIndex == undefined) {
                maxTabIndex = 100;
            }

            var tempIndex = currentTabIndex + 1;
            while (!$('[tabindex='+ tempIndex+ ']')[0] || tempIndex === maxTabIndex) {
                tempIndex++;
            }

            return $('[tabindex=' + tempIndex + ']')[0];
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, does it work if you just have e.preventDefault(); ?

Comment: Np, i think this will depend on the browser. I think it won't work with Chrome almost for sure. You can always do something like: var preventEvent = e.preventDefault || e.htmlEvent.preventDefault; preventEvent();

Comment: actually, e.preventDefault will work in Gecko and webkit. With trident (IE) you should use event.returnValue = false;

Answer (score 1):

No `.focus()` doesn't click the button or submits the form: http://jsbin.com/onirac/1/edit

It does exactly what you want it to.