# How can I put a button in the down state?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have a button, which goes into a down state when someone clicks on it, but before the mouse is released.

Now suppose instead that someone presses the 'a' key, I want the button to go into the down state, until the key is released, at which point it is triggered. Is this possible?

Comment: Interesting...not sure if this is possible; might have to use images or styling to fake it.

Comment: Add a KeyListener. When a key is pressed, add it to an array of the currently pressed keys. When it's released, remove it from the array. Use that array to check which keys are pressed.

Comment: @Casebash, to be clear...  ...do you mean that you want a visible button which looks like it's pressed, when you push "a", and then looks like it's released when you release "a", and then triggers whatever the button was meant to do?

Comment: Casebash, If you know the x and y of the button you can do a mouse event simulation on that button till the key is pressed. But this is not a very optimal solution

Comment: *Related:* http://stackoverflow.com/q/12584830/1563422

Comment: @zachlatta: I can do the key aspect, I just don't know how to make it look like a button is being pushed down

Comment: Do you want to use browser's default button styles or use custom css?

Comment: @archil: Default style if at all possible

Comment: @archil with custom css this is of course kids play ;-)

Comment: @Casebash ok. It's very simple with custom styles, I do not know how can it be done with browser ones. Maybe you could make your css for button to look like as browser default.

Comment: I have added an edit on my research progress, trying to find a way to hack into using accesskey  attribute of the button. unfortunately  I'll have to continue it later this earning as i have to logoff right now..

Comment: So I believe that the final answer is: not possible for default style buttons, is possible for custom styled buttons .. seed 'edit 2' of my answer.

Comment: Related: [Any way to keep an html button pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238314/any-way-to-keep-an-html-button-pressed)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After dooing some research here is the final answer I got:

You can trigger `mousedown` or `mouseup` events on a button element using `keyup` and `keydown`
if your button is programmed to change its style according to these events than you are good to go.

See this fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/FwKEQ/15/

Note that if you use jQuery's UI components than it does work. But for standard buttons there is no way that you can move them to their pressed state using javascript

html:

```
<button id="jQbutton">Press 'A' to move me to pressed state</button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $( "#jQbutton" ).button();

    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        if ((event.keyCode === 97)||(event.keyCode === 65))
            $("#jQbutton").mousedown();
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        if ((event.keyCode === 97)||(event.keyCode === 65))
            $("#jQbutton").mouseup();
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

There might be a hack that we could utilize:
using `accesskey` for the button element and then try to simulate the accesskey press (that i am not sure if possible)
here is where i'm at so far http://jsfiddle.net/FwKEQ/28/

**EDIT 2:**
So looking further into this topic i have found the following:

1. Default buttons (without styles) are rendered by the OS, I was not able to find a formal proof for that but if you try to load the same page using a mac OS you'll get mac OS style buttons while in windows you will get the "ugly" gray button.
2. Because the default buttons are rendered by the OS they comply to OS events meaning events that are sent by the browser and are trusted.
3. this is not true for custom styled buttons as they comply to CSS an JS to change their appearance on press that is why the JQ button is affected by JS.

so to summarize you would need a trusted press event to fire on a default button to change its style and that cannot be done due to security constraints.

read a bit more about trusted events here: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events

and if someone could find a formal reference with regards to the default buttons being rendered by the OS please comment or edit this answer.

Comment: +1; best solution for this problem. Anyway, here's a slightly optimized version of your code http://jsfiddle.net/eyecatchup/LYNXM/1/

Comment: Is this working as expected in FF and Chrome. When I press A nothing happens for the default button. But the jQuery UI button is changing style.

Comment: @kiranvj This is not working for the default button only for the jQuery .. that is the answere.. for now there is no option to simulate a pressed state for default buttons as they are rendered by the OS and not by the browser but i am trying to find a hack that will utilize the accesskey and simulate the require keypress.

Answer (score 8):

> Unfortunately the rendering of the active state on default buttons neither
>   is a simple matter of css styling nor can be easily changed by applying
>   javascript.

An option to do this on default buttons is to use the **hotkeys jquery plugin**: https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys or implement alternative key codes for different browsers.

and to **apply 50% opacity** to the default button when pressed (to indicate the keydown).

(To me it seems almost perfect ;-) It probably is as good as it can easily get to work across platforms and browsers using default buttons.

[jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XuU6V/2/embedded/result/)

and the code ...

**html:**

```
<button id="test">Test Button</button>
Selected: <span class="selected" id="out"></span>
```

**javascript:**

```
$('#test').click(function () {
    fn_up();
});
fn_down = function(event){
    $('#test').css("opacity", 0.5);
    $('#test').focus();
    event.preventDefault();
}
fn_up = function(event){
    $('#test').css("opacity", 1);
    $('#out').append(" test");
    event.preventDefault();
}

//to bind the event to the 'a' key
$(document).bind('keydown','a', fn_down); 
$(document).bind('keyup','a', fn_up);

//to get the same effect with the 'space' key
$(document).bind('keydown','space', fn);
$(document).bind('keyup','space', fn2);
```

In the fiddle I apply it to the space button and the mousedown/up to achieve the same effect with all events (but you could just use it with the 'a' key ... this is a matter of taste).

Comment: +1 it is a neat trick.. It is not really a "button-down" style but it still gives the required UI feedback.

Comment: thanks. yes - because of the unconsistent button-down redering it is impossible to do a much better cros-platform effect. Opacity 0.5 is often actually the default "disabled" effect on buttons, but I have been using it to simulate pressed state when using buttons instead of checkboxes or radios: http://jsfiddle.net/DDgnU/ and I thik it is almost as good as we can get it.

Comment: instead of lowering the opacity and making the default button lighter, you could also darken the button using `filter: brightnes(75%)` or something like this [ I think there might be the need for vendor prefixes (like -moz- and -webkit-) ]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a jsfiddel that shows how it's done using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/KHhvm/2/

The important part:

```
$("#textInput").keydown(function(event) {
    var charCodeFor_a = 65;
    if ( event.which == charCodeFor_a ) {

        // "click" on the button
        $('#button').mousedown();
        // make the button look "clicked"
        $('#button').addClass('fakeButtonDown');

        // do some stuff here...

        // release the button later using $('#button').mousedown();
    }
});
```

The button event is triggered when entering "a" in the input field. But as Mark pointed out you need to fake the styling for the clicked button because the browser doesn't do it.

**Edit:** I'm not sure if you're using jQuery in your project. I just wanted to show that it is possible at all. If it can be done with the jQuery library there is also a way to do it in pure javascript. ;)

Comment: When I type "a" in the input field, the button goes "down", however, it doesn't return

Comment: Yes I only added he mousedown event because that's what you asked for. ;) you could just as easily add the .mouseup () event too.